# SVG animation diagonal viewbox

Tags: css, animation, svg

I want to be able to make a design like this:

https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/bromkj/ello_everyone_this_is_a_ui_i_made_in_adobe_xd/

You can find my site at: [El Paso Texas Graphic Design and Web Design | Desert Sun Studio](https://www.desertsunstudio.com)

It's basic set up is having two fixed SVG's on different z-indexes on top of a orange HTML and body.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Oxygen", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: #A36D00;
} 

#left-panel{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  animation-name: left-panelmove;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

#right-panel{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  animation-name: right-panelmove;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}
```

You can see that the SVG's are masked as a rectangle when this animation runs:

```css
@keyframes right-panelmove {
    from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
    to {transform: translate(15%, 10%);}
}

@keyframes left-panelmove {
    from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
    to {transform: translate(-15%, -10%);}
}
```

However you can see that I have my black square on my SVG's much larger than the artboard.

[image: svgs on artboards]

[image: svgs on artboards]

I was wondering if there was anything I can do to this code to make the SVG's run all the way across the screen diagonally, specifically to the viewbox:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="ab9dac86-5d7c-460b-b35e-9ae3db46aedc"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
     style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: If this where me. I would recreate the svg @45 degress. Create the slice vertically with a horizontal curtain and then in css rotate the animation back 45 degrees to a normal angle and animate.

Comment: @DreamTek can you please elaborate, tried rotating the square svgs and it wouldnt cover half the screen.

Comment: You can just make your black shapes extra large. Then set `overflow: visible` on the SVG.  As long as they are large enough to cover the typical screen sizes, the black should reach to the edge of your page.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau thank you, this was the gist of the issue; i was applying my animations to the parent object

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes right-panelmove {
    from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
    to {transform: translate(15%, 10%);}
}

@keyframes left-panelmove {
    from {transform: translate(0, 0);}
    to {transform: translate(-15%, -10%);}
}

.left-panelmove{
  animation-name: left-panelmove;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

.right-panelmove{
  animation-name: right-panelmove;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}
```

i moved the @keyframes and class to appropriate SVG (left and right) inside the SVG style tag and it worked perfectly.